# MongoDB : Map Reduce : Create one sub-document from another one

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongodb collection which has documents like this :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("safdsd435tdg54trgds"),
"startDate" : ISODate("2013-07-02T17:35:01.000Z"),
"endDate" : ISODate("2013-08-02T17:35:01.000Z"),
"active" : true,
"channels" : [ 
    1, 2, 3, 4
],
```

}

I want to convert this to something like this :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("safdsd435tdg54trgds"),
"startDate" : ISODate("2013-07-02T17:35:01.000Z"),
"endDate" : ISODate("2013-08-02T17:35:01.000Z"),
"active" : true,
"channels" : [ 
    1, 2, 3, 4
],
"tags" :[ 
            {
                "name": one
                "type": channel
            },
            {
                "name": two
                "type": channel
            },
            {
                "name": three
                "type": channel
            },
            {
                "name": four
                "type": channel
            }
        ]           
}
```

I already have a mapping of what 1,2,3,4 mean. Just for the sake of simplicity I put them as their alphabetical format. the values could be different, but they're static mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be trying to do this update without a big iteration of your collection, So you "could" do this with mapReduce, albeit in a very "mapReduce way" as it has it's own way of doing things.

So first you want to define a **mapper** that encapsulates your current document :

```js
var mapFunction = function (){

    var key = this._id;

    var value = {
       startDate: this.startDate,
       endDate: this.endDate,
       active: this.active,
       channels: this.channels

    };

    emit( key, value );
};
```

Now here the **reducer** is actually not going to be called as all the keys from the **mapper** will be unique, being of course the `_id` values from the *original* document. But to make the call happy:

```js
var reduceFunction = function(){};
```

As this is a **one to one** thing this will go to **finalize**. It could be in the **mapper**, but for cleanliness sake

```js
var finalizeFunction = function (key, reducedValue) {

    var tags = [
        { name: "one", type: "channel" },
        { name: "two", type: "channel" },
        { name: "three", type: "channel" },
        { name: "four", type: "channel" }
    ];

    reducedValue.tags = [];

    reducedValue.channels.forEach(function(channel) {
        reducedValue.tags.push( tags[ channel -1 ] );
    });

    return reducedValue;

};
```

Then call the mapReduce:

```js
 db.docs.mapReduce( 
     mapFunction,
     reduceFunction,
    { 
        out: { replace: "newdocs" },
        finalize: finalizeFunction 
    }
 )
```

So that will output to a **new collection**, but in the way that mapReduce does it so you have this:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53112b2d0ceb66905ae41259"),
    "value" : {
            "startDate" : ISODate("2013-07-02T17:35:01Z"),
            "endDate" : ISODate("2013-08-02T17:35:01Z"),
            "active" : true,
            "channels" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ],
            "tags" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "one",
                        "type" : "channel"
                    },
                    {
                        "name" : "two",
                        "type" : "channel"
                    },
                    {
                        "name" : "three",
                        "type" : "channel"
                    },
                    {
                        "name" : "four",
                        "type" : "channel"
                    }
            ]
    }
}
```

So all your document fields other than `_id` are stuck under that `value` field, so that's not the document that you want. But that is **how** mapReduce works.

If you really need to **get out of jail** from this and are willing to wait a bit, the upcoming 2.6 release has added an [**`$out`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) pipeline stage. So you *"could"* transform the documents in your **new collection** with [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) like this:

```js
db.newdocs.aggregate([

    // Transform the document
    {"$project": { 
        "startDate": "$value.startDate",
        "endDate":   "$value.endDate",
        "active":    "$value.active",
        "channels":  "$value.channels",
        "tags":      "$value.tags"
    }},

    // Output to new collection
    {"$out": "fixeddocs" }

])
```

So that will be right. But of course this is not your original collection. So to back to that state you are going to have to [**`.drop()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/) collections and use [**`.renameCollection()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/#db.collection.renameCollection) :

```js
db.newdocs.drop();

db.docs.drop();

db.fixeddocs.renameCollection("docs");
```

Now please **READ** the documentation carefully on this, there are several limitations, and of course you would have to re-create indexes as well.

All of this, and in particular the last stage is going to result in a **lot** of disk thrashing and also keep in mind that you are dropping collections here. It almost certainly is a case for taking access to your database off-line while this is performed.

And even as such the **dangers** here are real enough that perhaps you can just live with running an iterative loop to update the documents, using arbitrary JavaScript. And if you **really** must have to do so, you could always do that using [**`db.eval()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/) to have that all execute on the server. But **if** you do, then **please read the documentation** for that very carefully as well.

But for completeness even if I'm not advocating this:

```js
db.eval(function(){

    db.docs.find().forEach(function(document) {

        var tags = [
            { name: "one", type: "channel" },
            { name: "two", type: "channel" },
            { name: "three", type: "channel" },
            { name: "four", type: "channel" }
        ];

        document.tags = [];

        document.channels.forEach(function(channel) {
             document.tags.push( tags[ channel -1 ] );
        });

        var id = document._id;
        delete document._id;           

        db.docs.update({ "_id": id },document);

    });

})
```

Comment: all the documents don't necessarily have a vvalue for channel, so how do I put a null check and not iterate when it's a null value.

Comment: @PiHorse Perhaps the easiest thing to do is skip them entirely with the query selection: {"channel": {"$exists": true}}. Depending on your chosen method you may also then need the reverse condition in order to merge the results.